# race condition in async / await socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets, async-await

This send method will fail periodically because control is returned to the calling thread, and `Send` is called again just as the socket is opened.

I am using Stephen Toub's class: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx

This causes the exception: **A connect request was made on an already connected socket.**
What's the correct approach to ensure that the asynchronous method doesn't suffer this fate. Basically the send cannot actually complete before the connection is made.

```
    public async Task Send(byte[] tosend)
    {
        // this code is not correct / not thread safe.
        if (this.socket.Connected)
            await this.StartSending(tosend);
        else
            await StartConnecting(tosend);
    }

    private async Task StartSending(byte[] tosend)
    {
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.SetBuffer(tosend, 0, tosend.Length);
        var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);
        await this.socket.SendAsync(awaitable);
    }

    private async Task StartConnecting(byte[] tosend)
    {
        var local = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        var ep = new IPEndPoint(local.AddressList.First(_ => _.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork), this.port);
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs() { RemoteEndPoint = ep };
        var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);
        await this.socket.ConnectAsync(awaitable);
        await StartSending(tosend);
    }
```

my test just calls `Send` very quickly in succession.

```
var sends = arrays.Select(_ => writer.Send(_)).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(sends);
```

sometimes the code above works just fine, and the socket is connected, `socket.Connected` is set to true 'on time'. Other times the call to `this.socket.ConnectAsync` happens more than once.

Comment: Can you clarify "control is returned to the calling thread?"

Comment: Sure, Send is called, which in turn calls StartConnecting and ConnectAsync. The next call to Send is then called which calls StartConnecting again as socket.Connected is still not true. The first connect is successful, and the second one throws an exception. The exception is intermittent. I have to run the tests a couple of times to reproduce the problem, as some of the time the socket is opened in time. My understanding of await is that it returns control without blocking - that is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to `Send` should be awaited, both so you know the connection has established and also so that you know that your data is being sent sequentially. This would better be handled by a `foreach` loop than `.Select`.

```
foreach (var data in arrays)
    await writer.Send(data);
```

Presumably you create the variable `sends` so that you can `Task.WhenAll` on it. Unfortunately this won't work for the reason you already discovered. You could possibly solve this with a separate method called `Connect` that async-ly connects to the remote host but does *not* send the data. You could then do:

```
await writer.Connect();
var sends = arrays.Select(_ => writer.Send(_)).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks, I am still trying to wrap my head around the asynchronous model... I think it should be easier to specify task dependencies, which is basically what I need here. A continuation of sorts.

Comment: it's a mouthful, but this will also work:             var sends = writer
                .Send(arrays.First())
                .ContinueWith(x => Task.WaitAll(arrays.Skip(1).Select(_ => writer.Send(_)).ToArray()), cancellationTokenSource.Token);